# Manually simulate function calls in R

Tags: r, debugging

My goal is to be able to manually step through function calls in R (without using e.g. debugonce). My current idea is the following:

```r
# standard function call 
f = function(x) {
  print(x)
  return(x)
}
f(1) 
#> [1] 1
#> [1] 1

## manually constructing a function call
func_env = new.env() 
delayedAssign("x", 1, eval.env = func_env) 
eval(expression(print(x)), envir = func_env)
#> [1] 1
eval(expression(return(x)), envir = func_env)
#> [1] 1
# standard function call 
f = function(x) {
  print(x)
  return(x)
}
f(1) 
#> [1] 1
#> [1] 1

## manually constructing a function call
func_env = new.env() 
delayedAssign("x", 1, eval.env = func_env) 
eval(expression(print(x)), envir = func_env)
#> [1] 1
eval(expression(return(x)), envir = func_env)
#> [1] 1
```

But I am wondering what the exact differences between these two "methods" are, e.g. with respect to something like `on.exit` or scoping.

I would appreciate any help on that matter.

Comment: Off the top of my head I can think of a few differences, yes. However, the question is *why* you want to use this technique rather than conventional tracing. The answer will probably depend on your reasons. Can you go into a bit more detail?

Comment: See [here](https://github.com/ManuelHentschel/VSCode-R-Debugger/issues/156) 
Tbh I don't really understand all of it I am just trying to help :D

Comment: What are the differences that you can think of?

Comment: The search path can be handled I think

Comment: (1) You don’t have a call stack, so variables are looked up differently. (2) Everything else that relies on a call stack (you’ve mentioned the case of `on.exit`) will behave differently. (3) The function environment isn’t the same as the calling environment (this is orthogonal to the call stack). (4) I *think* R internally handles arguments different from regular promises, but I don’t know any details. — Anyway, FYI, Nvim-R doesn’t work with DAP but it comes with (limited) support for interactive debugging via the regular trace mechanisms, you might want to look there for ideas.